# How to check update

Tags: ios, app-store, auto-update

I have developed an app running on iPhone. The app has a function called "check update" to check if there is a newer version(only check version and prompt the user, doesn't really download and update). The app has not submitted to App Store. how can I implement this functionality? The results I searched from elsewhere are using format like this:

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=284910350

Where can I get the "id" field? If the "id" is generated after submitted to the app store, then how to check newest version?

Comment: Who's app I'd are you trying to check? Anyone's app or the app you are trying to check for update is yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need to submit to the Apple Store in order to get your Application ID.

But you need to be part of the iOS Developer Program so you can go on https://itunesconnect.apple.com and "Add a new App".
If you're not ready to fill all the information just enter some random text and random picture as you can change them later.
Be carefull, from memory I'm not sure you can change the name of the App itself.

When done, click on your app. The new page will have a link call "View in App Store" of course if you click it you will get the information that the app your requested is not currently available.
But you are interested in the link itself as it contain the ID of your "future" app.

It should look like:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/your-app/**id592073786**?ls=1&mt=8

Where 592073786 is the id of your app.

Comment: Many thanks! I will check it out. Anyway, I have found a way using app name while waiting for your answer. It's like:    https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=yelp&country=us&entity=software      where "yelp" is the app name. The JSON string it returned contains "version" field. Thank you again.